# An element of a group $G$ is not conjugate to its inverse if $\lvert G\rvert$ is odd

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

> Prove that if $G$ is a finite group of odd order, then no $x\in$$G$ , other than $x=1$, is conjugate to its inverse.

This question is from Advanced Modern Algebra (exer 2.79) by Joseph J. Rotman.

The hint states that if $x$ and $x^{-1}$ are conjugate, how many elements are in $x^{G}$?

What I know so far:

1. $\left\lvert x^{G}\right\rvert$ is odd (greater than 1, otherwise it's in the center) and is a divisor of |$G$|
2. |Z($G$)| has a common factor (other than 1) with size of the orbit $\left\lvert x^{G}\right\rvert$ so that the center is not just the identity. This is from the class equation.
3. The centralizer of $x$ has odd size and $\lvert C_{G}(x) \rvert \cdot \lvert x^{G}\rvert=\lvert G\rvert$

I don't see the implication of $x$ and its inverse being conjugate has other than their orbits having the same size and laying in the same conjugacy class.

Is the info I have useful? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your second observation is false. Groups of odd order can have trivial center. Even if they have non-trivial center, the size of a class is not related to the size of the center: the non-abelian group of order 105 with non-trivial center has classes of sizes 1, 3, 7, but a center of size 5.

Comment: Wouldn't a conjugacy class of size one just mean that element is in the center? Thanks for catching my false observation.

Comment: You may find this link useful: https://yutsumura.com/if-a-group-is-of-odd-order-then-any-nonidentity-element-is-not-conjugate-to-its-inverse/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Suppose $x \neq 1$ is conjugate to $x^{-1}$.
Let $C(x)$ be the conjugate class containing $x$.
If $x = x^{-1}$, then $x^2 = 1$.
Hence $|G|$ is divisible by $2$.
This is a contradiction.
Hence $x \neq x^{-1}$.
Since $|C(x)|$ is odd, $C(x)$ contains $y$ which is neither $x$ nor $x^{-1}$.
Since $x$ is conjugate to $y$, $x^{-1}$ is conjugate to $y^{-1}$.
Hence $y^{-1} \in C(x)$.
Since $y \neq y^{-1}$, we must conclude that $|C(x)|$ is even.
This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Your point 1. is very useful. I don't think I need the other points; here's how I would proceed:

Try listing the elements of $x^G$. Well, we know $x$ is in there, and $x^{-1}$. If these two are distinct, then we know they're not the *only* two, because you told us that $|x^G|$ was odd. So some $y$ is in there too. But now what about $y^{-1}$?

Can you come up with a good reason why $x$ and $x^{-1}$ are distinct?

Comment: x and its inverse are distinct otherwise (as mentioned in another suggestion) there would be an element of even order, but if that was true then the order of that element should divide the order of G. That can't happen as G has odd size. Thank you.

Comment: Right, the answer Makoto Kato gave was pretty much what I was hinting at.