# Show that elements are not conjugate to their inverse in groups of odd order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, group-actions

> Show that if G is a group of odd order, then no $x\in G$ other than the
>   identity is conjugate to its inverse.

We can't have elements of order 2, since by Lagrange theorem this would mean we would have the subgroup generated by that element would have to divide the order of the group, but G is odd so this can't happen. Hence we can't have $x = x^{-1}$.

Now suppose there exists element $x\in G$ such that $x^{-1}=gxg^{-1}$ for some $g\in G$. Suppose that $y\in\operatorname{Orb}_G(x)$, so we have $y=qxq^{-1}$. Then
$y^{-1}=qx^{-1}q^{-1}=qgxg^{-1}q^{-1}$, which implies that $y^{-1}\in\operatorname{Orb}_G(x)$.

So for each $y\in\operatorname{Orb}_G(x)$ we will also have $y^{-1}\in \operatorname{Orb}_G(x)$, so $\operatorname{Orb}_G(x)$ must be even, but by orbit-stabilizer theorem we have $|\operatorname{Orb}_G(x)|=[G:C_G(x)]$, where $C_G(i)$ is the centralizer of group $G$ for element $x$, but by Lagrange this must divide order of group $G$, which is odd, so this can't happen. Therefore our original assumption is wrong and we get our result.

Comment: Why does $y,y^{-1}\in\operatorname{Orb}_G(x)$ imply that $|\operatorname{Orb}_G(x)|$ is even? Note that then you could simplify the argument by noting that $x,x^{-1}\in\operatorname{Orb}_G(x)$.

Comment: By the way more common term for orbit of the conjugacy action is the conjugacy class.

Comment: since for any element y in G it has a $y^{-1}$ in Orb_G(x), so the orbit consist of the all the pairs $y,y^{-1}\ \in\ Orb_G(x)$.

Comment: @Servaes He is claiming for 'every' $y$ in the conjugacy class, the inverse is also in the conjugacy class.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197828/an-element-of-a-group-g-is-not-conjugate-to-its-inverse-if-lvert-g-rvert-is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line of reasoning is correct, but the way the argument is written out is not entirely correct:

1. You first conclude that we cannot have $x=x^{-1}$, but we have $e=e^{-1}$. Maybe you mean for any $x\in G$ other than $x=e$?
2. From $y,y^{-1}\in\operatorname{Orb}_G(x)$ you conclude that the order of $\operatorname{Orb}_G(x)$ must be even. But what if $y=y^{-1}$ for some $y\in\operatorname{Orb}_G(x)$? Again you must treat the case $x=e$ separately.

Apart from this your proof is sound. As a side note, as user Jack Yoon comments, a more common notation for $\operatorname{Orb}_G(x)$ would be $\operatorname{Cl}_G(x)$, which is the conjugacy class of $x$ in $G$.

Comment: Regarding point 2: $y = y^{-1}$ cannot be by (1), or am I misunderstanding your comment on this?

Comment: yeah point 2 it can't happen because of 1.

Comment: Point 2 can happen, but only for $x=e$. So what might be confusing is that I both points concern the same exceptional case.