# not order $2$ implies not conjugate.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is a question I had in exam I failed miserablly perhaps someone can find me a solution to this exercise.

Let $G$ be a group and let $g\neq e$ be an element in $G$ such that its order is not $2$. It's given that in the conjugacy class of $g$ there's an odd finite number of elements. prove that $g$ is not conjugate to $g^{-1}$.

Here's what I wrote:
Suppose $a_1,\ldots,a_{2n+1}$ are elements in the conjugacy class of $g$, i.e there exists $h_i\in G$ such that:$a_i=h_igh_i^{-1}$.If one of them, say $a_1$ were $g^{-1}$ then we could write down: $g^{2n+1}=\prod_i h_i^{-1}a_ih_i$.

But then how to get a contradiction?

Comment: Well, if $g=e$ then it's order is not $2$, it has an odd number of elements conjugate to itself, and it is congugate to its inverse.  Did you mean to write "if the order is $>2$" or something like that?

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197828/an-element-of-a-group-g-is-not-conjugate-to-its-inverse-if-lvert-g-rvert-is) is a similar question.

Comment: @lulu yes it's order is greater than $2$.

Comment: @lulu it's similar but not the same question.

Comment: But it's the same idea: if $x$ is conjugate to $y$, then $x^{-1}$ is conjugate to $y^{-1}$. That means that if $x$ is conjugate to $x^{-1}$, then the conjugacy class of $x$ must be of even order, since whenever $y$ lies in the conjugacy class, so does $y^{-1}$ (and you never have $y=y^{-1}$, because $|y|=|x|\neq 2$).

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is essentially the same as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/197828/742).

Note that if $x$ is conjugate to $y$, then $x^{-1}$ is conjugate to $y^{-1}$, since $gxg^{-1}=y\iff gx^{-1}g^{-1} = y^{-1}$.  Moreover, if $y$ is conjugate to $x$, then the orders of $x$ and $y$ are equal.

So let $C$ be the conjugacy class of $x$. If $x^{-1}\in C$, then for every $y\in C$ we also have $y^{-1}\in C$ (since $y^{-1}\sim x^{-1}\sim x$). Morevoer, $y\neq y^{-1}$. Thus, the conjugacy class of $x$ is either infinite, or if finite then it has even order, since we can partition it into elements and their inverses.

Contrapositively, if $C$ has a finite odd number of elements, then we cannot have $x^{-1}\in C$.